# How to push image to hub.docker.com instead of docker.io

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-push

I want to push my image to my repo located in hub.docker.com .
When I run

```
docker push <hub-user>/<repo-name>:<tag>
```

It tries to push to docker.io but I wanted to push it to hub.docker.com as my repo  has been created there.
Could anyone please tell me how can I push image to hub.docker instead of docker.io

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the same thing.

- Hub.docker.com is the website.
- Docker.io is a common name for the registry (the actual hostname is different, but that gets handled automatically)

You browse the website and manage your account from Hub. You push and pull images to the docker engine with the registry.